# IOS Facebook App URL fb:// options besides publish

Tags: ios, facebook

There have been a couple of postings on this but it does not answer my direct question.

Currently we ware using the code like:

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"fb://publish/profile/me?text=%@",@"Some Link"];
BOOL canOpenURL = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:post]];

if ( canOpenURL && ![Utils isipad] && hFaceBookCheckAppFirst ) 
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:post]];
```

etc.  This works fine for positing.  It starts up the Facebook App and then the user can post, etc.

What are the other verbs that can be used instead of

```
fb://publish
```

Can't seem to find the docs on this.  Does not seem to be in the Facebook SDK docs, which brings up the web interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 fb://page/<id>
```

This works on iPhones.

Answer (score 6):

This website [lists all of the verbs associated with the fb:// handler.](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#Facebook)

Oddly I couldn't find this info on Facebook's site.

Comment: fb://pages/12414134132   with a valid page number does not work on IOS, just get the app with a blank screen

Comment: @ort11 according to the guide I sent you to, that is not a valid url.  only fb://pages is.  Also, an upvote and an accepted answer would be appreciated. thanks.